# non-intentional 'd' key disabling

Tags: keyboard

In an attempt to disable my <kbd>Insert</kbd> key I have disabled the <kbd>D</kbd> key on my keypad. I am desperate to get this key back but when I tried to retrace my steps it still doesn't work.

Edited for clarity

---

In an attempt to disable my <kbd>Insert</kbd> key I have disable one of the letters on my keypa (can you guess which). I am esperate to get this key back but when I trie to retrace my steps it still oesn't work. Help! I nee to get the <kbd>D</kbd> key back!

Comment: Sorry, but this is kinda funny. :D

Comment: Have you tried just restarting?

Comment: Give us some clues of which have you tried and what have you edited or changed so far.

Comment: How exactly did you disable it in the first place? What did you actually do to try to disable the other key and end up doing it to the `D` key?